# Determinant of Jacobian Integral zero

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is twice continuously differentiable and with compact support.

Is it true or false that $\det Df$, the determinant of the Jacobian satisfies $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\det Df\,dx\,dy=0$?

---

I was thinking in the lines of a counterexample, based on the Inverse Function Theorem. If we find a function, that is invertible at a point $p$, then the determinant $\det Df$ is nonzero there, and since the determinant is continuous, it will be nonzero in a neighborhood, leading to a counter-example?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I think I got it:
Let $f(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}f_1(x,y)\\
f_2(x,y)\end{pmatrix}$. Then $$\det Df=\left|\begin{matrix}\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y}\\
\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y}\end{matrix}\right|=\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x}\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y}\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x}.$$

Let $K$ be the support of $f$, so that $f_1$, $f_2$ vanishes on $\partial K$.

Note that
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(f_1\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y})&=\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x}\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y}+f_1\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x\partial y}\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(f_1\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x})&=\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y}\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x}+f_1\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y\partial x}.
\end{align*}

Let $M=f_1\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y}$, $L=f_1\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x}$. Then $$\det Df=\frac{\partial M}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}$$ since $\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x\partial y}=\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y\partial x}$.

Hence
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\det Df\,dx&=\int_K\left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}\right)\,dx\,dy\\
&=\int_{\partial K}(L\,dx+M\,dy)\tag{Green's Theorem}\\
&=0\tag{since $f_1$ vanishes on $\partial K$}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Yes, you got it. With one caveat: The boundary of the support can be really ugly (so ugly that you can't integrate over it). Take a $K$ with nice boundary that contains the support.